# Requests.get returns different results depending on which machine the program runs on

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, streamlit

I have a program that I've been trying to deploy on Streamlit Cloud... When running the program on my local machine, I get 1 set of results from my request.get, but when deployed to their servers, I get an entirely different set of results.

When using this locally, I wind up with a list of airlines, which I then combine with pricing data.

```py
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
browser = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q=fly{airline}+from+{origins}+to+{destination}+on+{date}+one+way{nonstop}', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.content, 'html.parser')
airlinefind = soup.find_all(class_='BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd')

for air in airlinefind:
    if airlinefind[x].string != None and airlinefind[x].string != 'Southwest':
        if len(airlinefind[x].string) > 19:
            st.write(f"Broke at 112; {airlinefind[x].string}, position {x} :thumbsdown:")
            break                                                   
        airlines.append(airlinefind[x].string)
        st.write(f"{airlinefind[x].string} :thumbsup:")                                                    
    x+=1

for air in airlines:
    if " " in air and air not in airlinelist:
        st.write(f"{air} ")
        pass
    else:
        new.append(air)
        st.write(f"{air} :airplane:")
```

When running this on Streamlit, however, I find that it is unable to retrieve this data, and instead gets an entirely different page.

I noticed that when opening the page in Brave incognito, it fails to load the chart, but it does do so correctly when in Edge incognito, even with JS disabled. (see attached photo for clarity).

[Edge incognito](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm5lj.png)

[Same search, in Brave Incognito](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIryy.png)

Any ideas of how to enforce a consistent result?

Comment: The site may be serving different content based on something like the IP or the location of the request.

Comment: If so, what would make Edge and Brave serve up different results while coming from the same device?

Comment: The user-agent string maybe; although that would be an odd thing for them to rely on. Maybe Google knows you're a bot and is screwing with you? It's hard to say. When I scraped YouTube search results for a project, YouTube would randomly send me results back in an entirely different format which would cause the scraping to fail. For the same exact search on the same device hosted in the same place, I would get differently formated pages. I assumed this was a protective measure.

Comment: Interesting... If that's the case, kind of weird that it works locally, then, as well as in my version hosted on Replit.